# How do I access an inner element of a ControlTemplate of Window.Resources?

Tags: wpf, code-behind, controltemplate

This question has been asked many times all over the place, but the solutions are either bad practice and not advised, or not generic to the problem.  Maybe this thread can fix that!

I have ControlTemplate within my Window:

```
<Window>
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonControl" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Grid Name="grdButtons" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Name="btnOk" Content="Ok" Width="75" Margin="10,10,255,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsDefault="True" Click="btnOk_Click" />
            <Button Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" Width="75"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,175,0" IsCancel="True" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
            <Button Name="btnApply" Content="Apply" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,95,0" Click="btnApply_Click" />
            <Button Name="btnDeleteRule"  Content="Delete" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,15,0" Click="btnDeleteRule_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>  
</Window.Resources>...
```

From codebehind, I need to enable or disable this button based on some actions I set up in code.  How can I properly access the button btnDeleteRule from code behind?  I have tried using FindName() but always get null.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to that is still:

1. Don't do it.
2. Bind `IsEnabled` to a property.

And if you want to disregard the *"don't do it"* you need to use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) on the template, not the control.

```
var button = (Button)someControl.Template.FindName("btnDeleteRule", someControl);
```

Comment: What do you mean don't do it?  It must be done, so how does Microsoft recommend we do it?  Could you go into more detail on how to bind isEnabled to a property?

Comment: @some_developer: Who says that it must be done? And where does Microsoft recommend it? If you don't know how bindings work see [the overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), i will not go into details on this here.